# Stay connected to download images with fsockopen?

Tags: php, http, keep-alive, fsockopen

I've made a basic script to get the html page and images. But I would like to continue to stay connected while I am retrieve pictures.
- What I did with the test script was kept on asking for addresses on the web server. But It did not work. 
So how do I do it or what have I done wrong?

Basic script:

```
function fetch( $server, $url, $port = 80, &$resp_head )
{
    if ( !$con = @fsockopen($server, $port, $error_number, $error_string, 30) ) return False;
    stream_set_timeout( $con, 8600 );

    // Reguest
    $qry_header = 'GET '.$url." HTTP/1.1\r\n";
    $qry_header .= 'Host: '.$server."\r\n";
    $qry_header .= 'User-Agent: Mihtyom; (+http://'.$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']."/)\r\n";
    $qry_header .= "Accept: */*\r\n";           //google check the 3 "Accept"
    $qry_header .= "Accept-Language: *\r\n";
    $qry_header .= "Accept-Encoding: *\r\n";
    $qry_header .= "Connection: Close\r\n\r\n";
    fwrite( $con, $qry_header );

    $inheader = True;
    $data = '';
    while (!feof( $con ))
    {
        $line = fgets( $con );
        if (!$inheader)
        {
            $data .= $line;
            continue;
        }
        if ($line == "\n" || $line == "\r\n")
        {
            $inheader = False;
            continue;
        }
        $resp_head[] = trim($line);
    }

    fclose( $con );

    return $data;
}
```

Test script:

```
function fetch( $server, $urls, $port = 80, &$resp_head )
{
    if ( !$con = @fsockopen($server, $port, $error_number, $error_string, 30) ) return False;
    stream_set_timeout( $con, 8600 );

    $resp_head = array();
    $data = array();
    foreach ($urls as $key => $url)
    {
        $inheader = True;
        $data[$key] = '';

        // Reguest
        $qry_header = 'GET '.$url." HTTP/1.1\r\n";
        $qry_header .= 'Host: '.$server."\r\n";
        $qry_header .= 'User-Agent: Mihtyom; (+http://'.$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']."/)\r\n";
        $qry_header .= "Accept: */*\r\n";           //google check the 3 "Accept"
        $qry_header .= "Accept-Language: *\r\n";
        $qry_header .= "Accept-Encoding: *\r\n";
        $qry_header .= "Connection: Close\r\n\r\n";
        fwrite( $con, $qry_header );

        while (!feof( $con ))
        {
            $line = fgets( $con );
            if (!$inheader)
            {
                $data[$key] .= $line;
                continue;
            }
            if ($line == "\n" || $line == "\r\n")
            {
                $inheader = False;
                continue;
            }
            $resp_head[$key][] = trim($line);
        }
    }
    fclose( $con );
    return $data;
}
```

New script (21-07-12 12:34):

```
function fetch( $server, $urls, $port = 80, &$resp_head )
{
    if ( !$con = @pfsockopen($server, $port, $error_number, $error_string, 30) ) return False;
    stream_set_timeout( $con, 8600 );

    $resp_head = array();
    $data = '';
    $i = count($urls);
    foreach ($urls as $key => $url )
    {
        $i--;

        // Reguest
        $qry_header = 'GET '.$url." HTTP/1.1\r\n";
        $qry_header .= 'Host: '.$server."\r\n";
        $qry_header .= 'User-Agent: Mihtyom; (+http://'.$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']."/)\r\n";
        $qry_header .= "Accept: */*\r\n";
        $qry_header .= "Accept-Language: *\r\n";
        $qry_header .= "Connection: ".($i == 0 ? 'Close' : 'keep-alive')."\r\n\r\n";
        fwrite( $con, $qry_header );
    }

    while (!feof( $con ))
    {
        $line = fgets( $con );
        if ($line == "\r\n\r\n" || $line == "\n\n") break;
        $data .= $line;
    }
    fclose( $con );
    return $data;
}
```

Comment: I recommend reading this to separate output. [How to easily decode HTTP-chunked encoded string when making raw HTTP request?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10793017/how-to-easily-decode-http-chunked-encoded-string-when-making-raw-http-request)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You specify `Connection: Close` in the HTTP header, which basically tells the server: "give me this one file and then close the connection immediately". You are actually forcing the connection to close yourself.

Instead, you can specify `Connection: Keep-Alive`, which tells the server (explicitly) to not close the TCP session so you can reuse it for another request.

However, the server must not accept this in any case - it may ignore your request and answer with `Connection: Close`. Also, each side of the connection may at any time close the connection and/or tell the other side to do so in the (next) header, via `Connection: Close`.

For a correct implementation, you should specify `Connection: Close` when your loop processes the last URL.

Find more details about persistent connections in [HTTP 1.1 / RFC 2068 Section 14.10](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2068.txt), [HTTP 1.1 / RFC 2616 Section 19.6.2](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2616.txt).

Comment: related http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7310339/under-what-circumstances-will-my-browser-attempt-to-re-use-a-tcp-connection-for

Comment: It's a little too much to read it through, here and now, but I save it. - Thank you. But instead, I have done the things you suggested and got responses xxx and xxx but it still does not work. - I have added the script above.

Comment: xxx and xxx = `Keep-Alive: timeout=5, max=1000` and `onnection: Keep-Alive`

Comment: Now I've gotten a notice.
Notice: fwrite() [<a href='function.fwrite'>function.fwrite</a>]: send of 156 bytes failed with errno=32 Broken pipe.....

Comment: @DibloDk that message means the server has already closed the connection